# Extracting parameter from auto template parameter callback

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am trying to deduce callback function parameters from a callback given as a template parameter. I have found this previous answer: [Can you extract types from template parameter function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033251/can-you-extract-types-from-template-parameter-function-signature) which looks like it'd be the answer, but somehow I cannot get this to work for what I want.

I have the following code:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename S>
struct signature;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct signature<R(Args...)>
{
    using return_type = R;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <auto callback>
void check_callback()
{
    using callback_type = decltype(callback);
    using arg1          = std::tuple_element_t<0, signature<callback_type>::argument_type>;
}

int main()
{
}
```

When compiling this with clang 6.0 as c++17 I get the following error:

> error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type;
>   did you forget 'typename'?

If I change the line defining callback_type to something like

```
using callback_type = void(int);
```

then it suddenly works, so given a valid function signature the code seems to work. Why won't it work when using decltype on a function coming from a template parameter?

Answer (score 5):

> Why won't it work when using decltype on a function coming from a template parameter?

Because in this case `callback_type` is a dependent name, which depends on the template parameter `callback`. Then you have to use the keyword [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename).

> Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, `typename` can be used to declare that a dependent name is a type.

So change the code to

```
using arg1 = std::tuple_element_t<0, typename signature<callback_type>::argument_type>;
//                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

`using callback_type = void(int);` doesn't have such issue; `callback_type` is an independent name.

Answer (score 3):

The full error message is (clang 9.0.0)

> ```
> prog.cc:17:51: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?
>     using arg1          = std::tuple_element_t<0, signature<callback_type>::argument_type>;
>                                                   ^
>                                                   typename
> ```

It is not the line above that is problematic, but you need to assure your compiler that `signature<callback_type>::argument_type` is a type, because that depends on the template parameter (via `decltype(callback)`). So you have to add `typename`:

```
using arg1          = std::tuple_element_t<0, typename signature<callback_type>::argument_type>;
                                           //   ^^
```

In case of `using callback_t = void(int);` there is no such ambiguity, because in that case `signature<callback_type>` does not depend on the template parameter `callback` and the compiler already knows that `signature<callback_type>::argument_type` is a type, not a value.